# How to make the text starts from left in edit text android

Tags: android

When i start entering in edit text, the text starts at the left border.I need to start entering text  one step after the border line of the edit text.how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Just add padding:

```
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
```

to your `EditText`

Answer (score 0):

Simply give padding left like below in your `EditText`

```
<EditText android:paddingLeft="5sp"/>
```